# Loading XIB file into UIInputViewController Swift

Tags: swift, xib

I have a custom keyboard which I want to add a XIB file to. However, whenever I try to load the keyboard it crashes right away. Hers is some code.

```
@IBOutlet var mainView:UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let xibViews = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("nib",owner: self,options:nil)
    self.mainView = xibViews[0] as! UIView
    self.view.addSubview(mainView)

    for v in self.mainView.subviews as! [UIButton] {

        v.addTarget(self, action: "tester", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }


}

func tester(){

    let proxy = textDocumentProxy
    proxy.insertText("chi")


}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error just sudden crashes when I try to open and test the keyboard

Comment: Is the mainView outlet connected?

Comment: Yes it is connected. But there is still a crash

Comment: What does the crash say, are you getting any debug info? Try replicating the crash on the device